# Type for a class as a function param

Tags: typescript, types, casting, nestjs

At first, Here is the core Interface :

```
// IMySuperInterface.interface.ts

export interface IMySuperInterface<T = any> {
  handle(arg?: any): Promise<T>;
}
```

Basically, I just need a common type for ==> **child class with an 'handle' function**.
Something like :

```
function MyDummyFunction (param: {{class that extends IMySuperInterface)}})
```

I try to *register* all the class in my app that implement my *'IMySyperInterface'*

```js
// MySuperImplementation.service.ts
@Feature('ReferenceA')
export class MySuperImplementation
  implements IMySuperInterface {

 constructor(private readonly logger: myLoggerService) {
    this.logger.setContext(this);
  }

  async handle(someDummy: any): Promise<void> {
    ....
  }
}
```

And Here the definition of the Decorator

```
// feature.decorator.ts
const _mapping = new Map<string, anyOrIdontKnowWhatToDo>();

export function Feature(key: string) {

  return function (target: **HERE WHAT CAN I WRITE  ??????**) {
    Feature.cache.set(key, target);
    return target;
  };
}
```

I try to find some sort of **'AtLeastContains<IMySuperInterface>'** or Type<IMySuperInterface>

with

```
export interface Type<T = any> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

But I get :

- neither : sorry but 'prototype' is missing in IMySuperInterface
- neither : sorry but logger in not compatible with 'Type' type

I am lost :(.. **How can I defined as a param of my function a Class that implements my Interface ?**
Note: The argument in the constructor of my class change all the time and also the argument of the function in the interface.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve here.  Where is `handle` actually called and what are the arguments that you pass to it?  Having an optional argument in the `interface` is almost certainly not what you want as that means implementations cannot require any arguments.  Either the arguments are defined and known, or `handle` is a function that takes no arguments.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to have a decorator exclusively apply to classes that implement a certain interface. I wish that were the case, but to my knowledge it's not doable

Comment: @LindaPaiste thank's for your comment, I add the handle function in the class. I unterstand your warning about the optional arguments in the interface but I can't clearly predict the incoming element here.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel In fact you can restrict where the decorator applied by changing the type of the target params in the decorator definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I learned it *is* possible to type a decorator to specific classes. Anyways, I was able to implement something similar like this:

```js
export function Command(
  options: CommandMetadata,
): <TFunction extends CommandRunner>(target: TFunction) => void | TFunction {
  return (target) => {
    Reflect.defineMetadata(CommandMeta, options, target);
    return target;
  };
}
```

This is a fully typed decorator, instead of using the `ClassDecorator` type so that I can set the `target`'s generic type correctly. Should be roughly what you're looking for. Just replace `CommandRunner` with your interface and the return of the anon `target` function with your decorator's logic.

Comment: You are a killer, the answer is correct but was fully good for me, Here is the answer : `export function Feature<K extends string>(
  key: K,
): <TFunction extends Class<IFeature>>(
  target: TFunction,
) => void | TFunction {

  return (target) => {
    Feature.cache.set(key, target);
    return target;
  };
}` with class = `export type Class<T = unknown, Arguments extends any[] = any[]> = new (
  ...arguments_: Arguments
) => T;`